# Failed to install application

Tags: android, apk

I am creating apk from the my application. Apk works in the first installation on my real device. But when I want to delete and later installation the same apk on my phone I get an error."Failed to install application.
"

My Project

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'

compileSdkVersion 29

buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"

Android Studio =3.4.2

I also tried other tools.and I created and tried another application. But they were also the same error.

Comment: try to uninstall from Settings> Apps> your app and uninstall. Sometimes app install for multiple users.

Comment: have you tried increasing the versionCode?

Comment: @LakhwinderSingh I uninstalled the application from my own device.

Comment: try to tun off play protects from the play store & then install the apk

Comment: @niks I have not tried.I'm installing apk to try.I dont use playstore now.

Comment: No just try that once. No need for play store.

Comment: @niks ı tried.but ı have same problem

Comment: try invalidate cache and restart in android studio.

Comment: @NavinKumar I tried it.

Comment: Now I am not getting errors when another computer also builds apk. But when I create apk on my own computer I get the error.I dont understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Try Build->Build Bundle(s)/APK(s)-> Build Apk(s) or Bundles(s) and then run the app again . Hope this helps

Comment: Thx so much for ansver.ı tried build apk.later try  genered signed apk v1 and v2.But I have same problem.

Comment: At first just try build apk(s), try not to generate signed apk(s).
If it didn't work again try File-> Invalidate cache and restart

Comment: ı tried File->invalid cache .later  tried build apk and ı have same problem.First instaling no problem.it is working.but when delete apk later install .it is not working.

Comment: For some devices you can try these:
1)Go to the developer option and in that disable MIUI optimization.You will be asked to reboot your phone. Reboot it and then run the app.
2) Also try  to disable Instant Run from Android Studio:
    File > Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment > Instant Run > Un-check (Enable Instant Run to hot swap code)
3)Go to Build --> Clean Project --> Run

Answer (score 0):

Delete all files in the directory YourProjectName\build\android-profile.

Comment: Thx so much for asnver.but ı dint find your tell folder.Now I am not getting errors when another computer also builds apk. But when I create apk on my own computer I get the error.

Answer (score 0):

I finded this solution.Now working .Thx so much @Konstantin Raspopov

Going to Google Play -> Play Protect and turning off Scanning device for security threats helped me.

source:https://stackoverflow.com/a/51335340/11840484